# How to shorten a string (but with a few exceptions) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have strings in Python that I want to shorten but unfortunately I don't know how to do that. So a little more precisely: The strings look like this, for example: `"Em"`, `"Bsus4"` or `"F7"`. I would like to shorten it so that only the first letter is there, but now comes my problem: the letters `"m"` and `"is"` after the first letter should not be shortened. Examples:

`"Em"` becomes `"Em"`.

`"Bsus4"` becomes `"B"`.

`"F7"` becomes `"F"`.

`"Fis7"` becomes `"Fis"`.

Does anyone have any idea how to express this in code?

Comment: Check the updated answer, add as many exceptions you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exceptions = ['m', 'is'] # enter your list here

def shorten(inputWord):
    flag = False
    for value in exceptions:
        if value == inputWord[1:]:
            return inputWord[:1] + value
            flag = True
    if not flag:
        return inputWord[:1]

print(shorten('Em'))
```

Comment: ```Updated Answer```  In case of repeated exception like ```Emm or Eisis``` what is expected ?

Comment: "Fisis" should then just become "Fis". So everything after the firtst "is" (or "m") should be deleted. Thank you very much. This is really helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use if/else statement satisfy your condition.

```
def slice(input):
    string = ''
    if input[1] == 'm':
        string = input[0:2]
    elif input[1:3] == 'is':
        string = input[0:3]
    else:
        string = input[0:1]
    return string


print(slice("Fis7"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to propose a solution that should work for all strings:

```
def shorten(string):
    result = string[0]
    max_length = len(string) - 1
    i = 0
    while i < max_length:
        i += 1
        char = string[i]
        if char == 'm':
            result += char
        elif char == 'i':
            i, result = find(string, i, result, max_length)
    return result

def find(string, i, result, length):
    if i < length:
        if string[i + 1] == 's':
            return i + 1, result + 'is'
    return i, result
```

Answer (score 0):

for one-liner fans:

```
list_of_str = ["Em", "Bsus4", "F7", "Fis7"]
print([item[0:2] if len(item)>1 and item[1] == "m" else item[0:3] if len(item)>2 and item[1:3] == "is" else item[0] for item in list_of_str])
```

output:

```
['Em', 'B', 'F', 'Fis']
```